# Creating DEB file for python application

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, pygtk, deb

I am new to python programming and this is my first serious python application. Also never created any public application for Ubuntu/GTK platform. Ultimate goal is to make this application available in Ubuntu software repository or similar repositories.

I have been looking up information about building packages and have came across some documents (e.g.http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/) and some packages like Py2deb but it's not clear to me how my application needs to be structured so that deb installer can do the right things

1. Application is dependent on some other python libraries which can be installed using apt-get install command. How to indicate this dependency
2. Application is dependent on some some python libraries which can be installed using PIP. How to ensure/install these libraries.
3. Application needs webkit3. I think this is part of standard ubuntu desktop install, but should I indicate explicit dependency? If yes, how to do that.
4. Application has its own resource files - non python files such images/templates etc. Where should these files go.

Current tree structure of the application can be seen at https://github.com/nhrdl/notesMD

Comment: If you hurry up there are Ubuntu SDK Days currently going on, I believe you can ask there as well: http://ubuntuonair.com/

Comment: Thanks, I saw the link, but looks like I have to watch videos latter. Day time work vs hobby work :)

Comment: I recommend you to use [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) for python packages (i.e. first you need to create functional python package). It can create RPM and DEB packages. See [this example](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/ConvertingPython), documentation and --help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an application that depends on webkit3 and other libraries, you can include the .deb file of the libraries inside your .deb and include a script that will install the libraries or you can just include the core python application in your deb file and just leave to the user the installation of the libraries by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

For the images, you can add them to a directory near your application to prevent any directory problems.

Hope this helps and good luck with your application. :)